# Is there any alternative to .watch() of mongodb in SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite

In MongoDB I used to use `db.collection.watch()` specially in mMngoose to know changes in database, so that I could apply socket.io events.
I'm looking same functionality but in SQL, so that if database changes such as in 'insert','updated','delete', I can do relevant socket events just like in MongoDB `watch()`.

Comment: Which database system are you using? SQL is "just" a query language, and details and features for notifications/events etc vary per actual underlying database management system.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel , I'm using testing with many databases, but as for now i'm using sqlite. but i'm also looking for postgresql. Thank you